# leftJoin does not get all the rows in the LEFT table

Tags: sql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following query

```
#Query 1
$count = User::where('users.status', '=', 1)
    ->leftJoin('deposits', 'users.id', '=', 'deposits.user_id')
    ->select('users.*')
    ->groupBy('deposits.user_id')
    ->count();

# Count == 71


# Query 2
User::where('users.status', '=', 1)->count()

# Count == 89
```

Please why I'm I not getting all the rows in the users table?

Ultmately, I'll like to run the following query

```
$resellers = User::where('users.status', '=', UserStatus::getUserStatusAsInteger('reseller') )
                    ->leftJoin('deposits', 'users.id', '=', 'deposits.user_id')
                    ->where('deposits.status', '=', 'completed')
                    ->where('deposits.created_at', '>=',  \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(25) )
                    ->having( DB::raw( 'sum( deposits.amount )') , '<', Settings::first()->min_reseller_deposit )
                    ->select('users.*',  DB::raw( 'sum( deposits.amount ) as `total_deposits`' ))
                    ->groupBy('users.id')
                    ->get();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are `left join`ing on a table, you still use a `join` condition and the query would return rows only that satisfy the condition. As there are no rows in the `right` table that don't match the condition, you wouldn't see `null` values showing up.

Comment: Please can you help me with another query that gets all the users together with their deposits. if they at all they have any deposits?

Comment: i am not sure..why you are using a `group by` in your statement. Can you try taking that off?

Comment: If I take that off, I'll get duplicate rows since a user can Have more than 1 deposit

Comment: from what you say, there are 89 rows in users table with status `1`. Is that what you are trying to get as your result?

Answer (score 0):

In your first query, the reason you don't get all rows back is because you're grouping by `deposits.user_id` which will not exist for all users.

```
->groupBy('deposits.user_id')
```

Instead you should group by `users.id`

In your second query, the reason you're not getting all rows in the left table is because you're referring to the right table, `deposits`, in your `where` clause, which means anytime there is no match on `deposits` those values will be null and your `where` fails.

The solution is to move the `where` conditions for `deposits` into your `left join`

```
leftJoin('deposits', function($join) {
    $join->on('deposits.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
         ->on('deposits.status','=',DB::raw("'completed'"))
         ->on('deposits.created_at', '>=',  \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(25);
})
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error. This stackover flow commenting markdown is very limited. You can see the error here https://gist.github.com/najela/802f9620f5b68865acae

Comment: @bePolite see update, you need to use `DB::raw` so `completed` is interpreted as a string and not a column